# how to solve this " Warning: Return value of low-level calls not used."?

Tags: solidity

specific code i have prob is

```
payable(marketingFeeReceiver).call{value: amountBNBMarketing, gas: 30000}("");
```

https://i.stack.imgur.com/jk9Z4.png

Comment: is there some `send()` in the calls at some depth level? then you proably aren't checking the return value of type `bool`

Comment: could you solve the problem? I have the same problem too.

Answer (score 1):

It is a warning. From the [documentation](https://docs.soliditylang.org/en/v0.8.6/units-and-global-variables.html#members-of-address-types) the signature for call is

```
<address>.call(bytes memory) returns (bool, bytes memory)
```

It returns a bool and a bytes array, bool is true when the call succeeded and false otherwise, the bytes array contains the returned value.

You can silence the warning validating the success of the call with:

```
(bool success, ) = payable(marketingFeeReceiver).call{value: amountBNBMarketing, gas: 30000}("");
require(success, "Call failed");
```

Answer (score 0):

As Ismael said, the signature for call is

```
<address>.call(bytes memory) returns (bool, bytes memory)
```

you can call the boolean to ensure the success of the call.

It is good to know that you can also decode the returned data (if any) as such:

```
(bool success, bytes memory data) = payable(marketingFeeReceiver).call{value: amountBNBMarketing, gas: 30000}("");
require(success, "Call failed");
uint256 decoded = abi.decode(data, (uint256));
```

**Note that I used uint256 for the decoded type but you can use strings, or bytes, or other kinds of native variable types**

Answer (score 0):

You can suppress the warning without using a `require` statement by doing the following:

```
(bool success,) = payable(marketingFeeReceiver).call{value: amountBNBMarketing, gas: 30000}("");
success;
```

Adding `success;` will mark the variable as used. This statement will be optimised out by the compiler so it does not increase gas fees. This pattern is used by the ERC-4337 entrypoint.

**Note**, in most cases the return value should be checked to prevent loss of funds. Only use this method if you are sure it is safe to ignore the return value.